# How do I synchronize keychains between computers?

Tags: macos, data-synchronization, keychain

I have two Macs running Lion on a home network that I use regularly, and I would like to keep my keychain files synchronized between them.

I add keychain entries on both machines, so I need to be able to merge (rather than overwrite) keychain files.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There used to be, as MobileMe did keychain syncing. Indeed, that was the only reason I was a subscriber.

Since iCloud, that feature is no longer available. I now use [1Password](https://agilebits.com/onepassword) for my password syncing. It isn't quite as good as keychain syncing (non-browser applications can't really use it), but for most stuff it's dandy.